c# switch expression usage with an array input
I am wondering if I can use switch expression with multpile input as an array. I tried it, that didn't work but maybe I am doing something wrong with the syntax. This is what I mean by multiple input:
public static string EvaluteIt(int[] rawClusterValues)
    {
        string result = "Unknown";

        switch(rawClusterValues)
        {
            case [0, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5]:
                {
                    result = "some result here";
                    break;
                }

            case [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]:
                {
                    result = "It is found";
                    break;
                }
            case [ 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]:
                {
                    result = "this is another result";
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    result = "result is default";
                    break;
                }

        }

        return result;
    }


What you want to check, Is rawClusterValues equivalent to any of the case? or any of the element from rawClusterValues is matching any element from case?

Better describe what not working means. Your code and syntax looks correct and working to me. If it does not maybe you have other expectations then me/us and we need to know that then.

The code should work as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xSGy2Y, what did you mean by that didn't work?

Yes, you can use list patterns in switch expressions just like in your example. It compiles and runs fine on the newest version of .NET. You can even use more advanced list patterns, like case [5, .., 10]. I pasted your example into here, with one additional case I mentioned: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cBQt04
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = EvaluteIt(new[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        
        var result2 = EvaluteIt(new[] { 5, 1, 4, 6, 10 });
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
    
    public static string EvaluteIt(int[] rawClusterValues)
    {
        string result = "Unknown";

        switch (rawClusterValues)
        {
            case [0, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5]:
                {
                    result = "some result here";
                    break;
                }
            case [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:
                {
                    result = "It is found";
                    break;
                }
            case [3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]:
                {
                    result = "this is another result";
                    break;
                }
            case [5, .., 10]:
                {
                    result = "Cool pattern";
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    result = "result is default";
                    break;
                }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

If you have any troubles with your code, "I tried it, that didn't work" is not enough to help you in any way. What exactly doesn't work?

You mixed up switch statement and switch expression in wording they are two different things. Therefore even if you showed a switch statement here an example for a switch expression doing the same. Used code from @Orion as base so you can easier compare statement vs. expression syntax.
public static string EvaluteIt(int[] rawClusterValues) => rawClusterValues switch
{
    [0, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5] => "some result here",
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => "It is found",
    [3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1] => "this is another result",
    [5, .., 10] => "Cool pattern",
    _ => "result is default"
};

